# Recursively finding subset sum

Tags: c, recursion, subset-sum

I am practicing on recursion and i wanted to try a very popular problem for recursion, the subset sum problem, but i wanted a little catch. I also want to print the subset if it exists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum){
    if (sum == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    if (set[n - 1] > sum)
        return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum);

    return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1]);
}

int main(){
    int set[] = { 3, 34, -4, -12, 5, 2, 1, 7, 9 };
    int sum = 0;
    int n = sizeof(set) / sizeof(set[0]);
    if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == 1)
        printf("Found a subset with given sum\n");
    else
        printf("No subset with given sum\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far. How would i implement it. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some days and i cant figure it out.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i store the subset in a matrix if it exists

Comment: One option is an `output` array that is the same size as the `set` array. You'll also need an `outputCount` that keeps track of how many numbers are in the `output` array. When using a number (the third recursive call in your code), add the number to the `output` array and increment the `outputCount`. If the recursive call returns `0`, then decrement the `outputCount`.